# How can I cast an object to some unknown class type？

Tags: c#

As we know, by reflection we can create an class instance, but the type is object. Here are some sample code.

```
  Type type = p.GetType();
  Type keyType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  Type valueType = type.GetGenericArguments()[1];

   var r = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>)
                .MakeGenericType(new Type[] { keyType, valueType })) 
                   as SerializableDictionary<? ,?>;
```

The SerializableDictionary is a subclass of Dictionary.  Why will I have to cast this object?
Because I want to add some elements into the SerilaizbleDictionary. The elements are from another dictioanry.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<?, ?> kvp in d)// d is another dictionary
{
   r.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

How can I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: The compiler needs to know what type `r` is so it can check if it has an `Add` method, etc. It doesn't know what type you are going to create at *runtime*. That's why you have to cast it.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `r.Add` above, btw.

Comment: Consider casting both dictionaries to the non-generic interface IDictionary instead.

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes your are right. It's r.add. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, "subclass" is not a .NET term.  Either `SerializableDictionary` inherits `Dictionary` or `SerializableDictionary` is derived from `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items are coming from another `Dictionary` then could you not simply write a generic method and let it handle the generic typing?

```
private SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToSerializable<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
    var output = new SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    foreach (var key in source.Keys)
    {
        output.Add(key, source[key]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: But the problem for me is that I don't know the generic type until the runtime. The code you offer is only available when we exactly know the types.

Comment: No, the whole point of generics is that they will work for any type you care to use at run time.  You can pass any `Dictionary` you want to that method and it will pass back a `SerializableDictionary` with the same type for the keys and the same type for the values.  It doesn't matter what types `TKey` and `TValue` are; the same method will work for any combination of types.

Comment: That said, the code does require that you have a `Dictionary` reference at run time and not an `Object` or something else more general.  The code you posted in your question suggests that is the case though.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination agagin. Yes this is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments consider casting to the [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) interface. Specifically the [`IDictionary.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.add.aspx) method.

```
Type type = p.GetType();
Type keyType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type valueType = type.GetGenericArguments()[1];

var dictionary =
    (IDictionary) Activator
        .CreateInstance(typeof(SerializableDictionary<,>)
        .MakeGenericType(new Type[] { keyType, valueType }));

foreach(var item in stronglyTypedDictionary)
{
    dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

For example:

```
// Assume dictionary is created using reflection
IDictionary dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var stronglyTypedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"hello", null} };

foreach(var item in stronglyTypedDictionary)
{
    dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Make sure that the types match between `dictionary` and `stronglyTypedDictionary`.